# shown dateaxis by all datetime not hour in amcharts4

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Im tired to try all paramter in dateAxis but it shown label date hour part

```
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm");
dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm";
// Setting up label rotation
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 45;
```

[image: image hown just hour in lable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting format for a "day", while your `DateAxis` is in "hour" mode. You need to set it for that. While you're at it make sure you set for period change as well:

```
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("hour", "YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm");
```

Make sure your [read this](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Formatting_date_and_time) about formats on `DateAxis`.